# How to cast Android views to an interface having a specific method?

Tags: java, android

I have a set of UI elements—TextView, EditText, and even custom views which all have setError(CharSequence error) method in them. I’m writing a simple utility class that can help me to call setError(null) so it sets them all in one go. For this, I wrote a utility class ValidationUtils which can be initialised like…

```
ValidationUtils validator = ValidationUtils.getInstance();
validator.put(etEmail);
validator.put(etPassword);
```

And in general validator’s put takes in a View object. The Android View class doesn’t seem to have a setError(CharSequence error) but the individual UI classes such as EditText do. I want to store all the entries from put inside a Map and then call a `validator.clearAll` to iterate over this map and call the setError in every class to set null. I have written an interface like:

```
public interface Validatable {
    void setError(CharSequence errorMsg);
}
```

But can’t quite figure out how I would proceed with making the elements added via put() cast to this interface so that I can call setError later.

Right now calling the put gives me `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText cannot be cast to Validatable`

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do that, since there's no way for you to make the base `View` class implement your interface. However, what you could do, is make your custom `View` classes implement that interface, and then do something like:

```
if (view instanceof Validatable) {
    Validatable.class.cast(view).setError(null);
} else if (view instanceof TextView) {
    TextView.class.cast(view).setError(null);
}
```

`EditText` extends `TextView`, so that should cover both of your cases for the framework classes.

Comment: You are right. But I think I may have found a way around this. The library “butterknife" seems to overcome this using JavaPoet to generate code during compile time that extends your existing activity class and implements the required interface (Unbinder in case of Butterknife) and can access the view field’s methods through that generated class.